# Install a package in Jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins

I am very new at Jenkins and trying to build my first pipeline.

What I want is for Jenkins to go to a git repo, compile all the .tex files into .pdfs and then save those .pdfs somewhere

I have figured out the first part for connecting to the git repo. my new problem is trying to compile the pdfs

right now my shell script is

```
cd latex
latexmk -pdf
```

(I've also tried with `pdflatex file.tex`, no change)
The builds are failing because the command latexmk is not found. I am trying to figure out how to install latexmk or something similar into Jenkins.

I've tried running commands in the shell like `pip install latexmk` but those get the same error of `pip` or `apt` not being installed. How can I install them so I can compile .tex into .pdfs?

Probably I'm going about this entirely wrong but this is just me kind of stumbling about blindly so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Jenkins is running on (I believe) some flavor of linux, I did not set up the server, it is run and hosted by another team member (who I am currently unable to ask). For this reason I'm not sure how to go about adding things to the path (like this answer sugests [Jenkins jasmine-node command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784211/jenkins-jasmine-node-command-not-found))

Comment: what OS is jenkins running on?

Comment: I believe it is on some flavor of linux, I did not set up the server, it is run and hosted by another team member (who I am currently unable to ask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this particular problem was to ssh into our Jenkins server and to `sudo apt-get install` all the necessary packages.

Packages cannot be installed from the shell commands in the build configuration.